# React-Native with pulling images from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, react-native

```html
uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
        const path = `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`;
    // uploadPhotoAsync = (uri, filename) => {

        return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const file = await response.blob();

            let upload = firebase
                .storage()
                .ref(path) //path
                .put(file);

            upload.on(
                "state_changed",
                snapshot => {},
                err => {
                    rej(err);
                },
                async () => {
                    const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    res(url);
                }
            );
        });
    };
```

So far I have this working where it saves my photos according to my the uid in firebase storage. 
So when I click storage I see a folder called photos/ from there there are uid folders depending on who is signed in, and in those are the images.

Question is how do I now pull them from storage to display all the images stored on there on my react native app?

Answer (score 0):

```
        uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
        const path = `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`;
        // uploadPhotoAsync = (uri, filename) => {

            return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
                const response = await fetch(uri);
                const file = await response.blob();

                let upload = firebase
                    .storage()
                    .ref(path) //path
                    .put(file);

                    upload.on(
                        "state_changed",
                        snapshot => {},
                        err => {
                            rej(err);
                        },
                        async () => {
                            const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                            //store this url in firebase db related to the user 
                            //e.g. `${userid}\photo\url` 
                            res(url);
                        }
                    );
                });
            };
```

You need to store the url, see the comments in code.
Then when you need to display/pull this image get the url from firebase db